# How can I make this gsub better?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to remove a few characters (@[]"") from strings in an array. Currently I have it working, but by using 3 gsubs, which is pretty silly. Is there a better way to do this?

```
array_name.collect! {|name| name.to_s.gsub(/\["@/, "").gsub(/\"/, "").gsub(/\]/, "")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, seems you can do

```
array_name.collect! { |name| name.to_s.gsub(/[@\[\]"]/, "") }
```

This removes the 4 characters `@`, `[`, `]`, `"` from `array_name`.

---

If you only want to remove whole instances of `["@` as your current method does, and then individual instances of `"` and `]`, then it seems you need 2 `gsub`s:

```
array_name.collect! { |name| name.to_s.gsub(/\["@/,"").gsub(/[\"\]/,"") }
```

The reason you would need two `gsub`s is because if you first removed all `"` first then it would leave instances of `["@` as just `[@`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about order, just look at the `delete` function:

```
array_name.map! { |name| name.to_s.delete '@[]"' }
```